# Icon fonts give margin between icon and text

Tags: css

I'm not a css pro. I want to give margin between icon and text. I tried this way. But results not similar to what i expected.

```
.user-details i{
  margin: 0 10px 0 -2px;
}
```

[image]

I want same space between icon and text.

Comment: Thats because icons are not the same `width`.

Comment: Yes. Is there any way to make this space similar. I have seen some similar approaches

Comment: Try with `display:inline-block;min-width: [width-of-largest-icon]px`.

Comment: Superb. Thanx bro.Totally worked

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I said in the comment, you can add :

```
.user-details i{
    margin: 0 10px 0 -2px;
    display: inline-block; /* so min-width can be used */
    min-width: [width-of-largest-icon]px;
}
```

Also, [don't forget about `inline-block` whitespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5078239/how-to-remove-the-space-between-inline-block-elements).

Answer (score 0):

Dushan, when i see your icon list picture,
I would like to suggest u try other two methods

:before :after methods

or

background:url(background-icon-image.jpg) **-10px** 0px no-repeat; 
The -10px 0px are background-position attributes, 
which Specifies the position of the background images
personally i used this one very often to align icons;